# UI Issue (Bottom bar i.e home and back button hiding UI components)

Tags: android

I have placed a bottom button on my UI, but the back and home button hiding my layout so I am not able to tap on bottom buttons, Please see the screen 1. I have attached, 
[[Current View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sr19b.jpg)

It should look like below screenshot, my bottom layout are overlapped by system UI components.  http://i63.tinypic.com/kcc5df.jpg

adding xml of layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<outworx.in.hangout.Utils.SoftKeyboardLsnedRelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/myLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/included_layout">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/user_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_cover_new"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">


        <include
            android:id="@+id/header_view"
            layout="@layout/top_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/welcometxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header_view"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Welcome "
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/header_text" />


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/vpPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/welcometxt"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

            >

            <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
                android:id="@+id/pager_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:paddingTop="4dp" />

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/floatingButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>


<include
    android:id="@+id/included_layout"
    layout="@layout/tabview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</outworx.in.hangout.Utils.SoftKeyboardLsnedRelativeLayout>
```

Comment: add layout file..

Comment: @Dhruv Tyagi I have attached link to screen

Comment: There is surely a problem in your xml layout. It's not possible to detect that just watching your screenshots. Please provide your xml codes.

Comment: add android:fitsSystemWindows="true" in your SoftKeyboardLsnedRelativeLayout tag, This may be helpful

Comment: http://i63.tinypic.com/kcc5df.jpg what I want

Answer (score 0):

This should work for all devices. Add the following code to onCreate() of activity:

```
boolean hasMenuKey = ViewConfiguration.get(context).hasPermanentMenuKey();
boolean hasBackKey = KeyCharacterMap.deviceHasKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);

if(!hasMenuKey && !hasBackKey) {
    int padding_in_dp = 48;  // 6 dps
    final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int padding_in_px = (int) (padding_in_dp * scale + 0.5f);
    myLayout.setPadding(0,0,0,padding_in_px); //Set Padding bottom to your parent layout
}
```

Hope this helps.